# Retrieve Image from SQLITE DB and open it in imageView using JFXbutton

Tags: database, sqlite, javafx

I'm trying to create desktop App (scenebuilder)  and  I want to retrieve path of Image from DATABASE (SQLITE) and Attach it to button  to open  it in `ImageView` but I'm facing a problem while doing that.

**Note:** I'm trying to learn Java

**My code**

```
@FXML
private ImageView imageView;
 @FXML
 void btn10 (ActionEvent event) {


Connection c = null;
Statement stmt = null;
try {
    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:sogeclair.sqlite");
    c.setAutoCommit(false);
    System.out.println("Opened database successfully");
    stmt = c.createStatement();

    String sql = "SELECT * FROM image WHERE rowid = 1" ;
    System.out.println(sql);
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( sql );
    while ( rs.next() ) {

        String path=rs.getString("imaging");
        imageView.setImage(new Image(path));

        System.out.println();
    }
    rs.close();
    stmt.close();
    c.close();

    } catch ( Exception e ) {
        System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
        System.exit(0);
    }
    System.out.println("Operation done successfully");
}
```

**and I got this in result**

```
Opened database successfully
SELECT * FROM image WHERE rowid = 1
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL: Invalid URL or resource not found
Deleting directory C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\NetBeansProjects\sogece\dist\run538077077
jfxsa-run:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 10 seconds)
```

and **MyDatabase**

[image]

All comments are welcome :D   help me please  :D

Comment: FYI: You should migrate to TryWithResources and you no longer need to used Class.forName if you have the last sqlite version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is code from a program I wrote that retrieves an image blob from sqlite. You can download and run the program from [here](https://github.com/sedj601/ContactsFx/tree/newBranch). It's running, but it's an incomplete program.

> In your code, once you get the image using ideas from my code then just use that image to set your ImageView.

```
        String sqlTCNote = "SELECT * FROM Company;";            
        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:contactFX.db");
             Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(); 
             ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery(sqlTCNote)) 
        {
            while(rset.next())
            {                
                Company c1 = new Company();
                c1.setName(rset.getString("company_name"));
                c1.setShortName(rset.getString("short_name"));
                c1.setStreet(rset.getString("street"));
                c1.setCity(rset.getString("city"));
                c1.setState(rset.getString("state"));
                c1.setZip(rset.getString("zip"));
                c1.setPhoneNumber(rset.getString("phone_number"));
                c1.setTollFreeNumber(rset.getString("toll_free_number"));
                c1.setEmailAddress(rset.getString("email_address"));
                c1.setMissionStatement(rset.getString("mission_statement"));
                c1.setPersonalNote(rset.getString("personal_note"));
                c1.setWebSiteAddress(rset.getString("website_address"));  

                //This is the part you are interested in!
                InputStream input = rset.getBinaryStream("image");
                InputStreamReader inputReader = new InputStreamReader(input);                        
                if(inputReader.ready())
                {
                    File tempFile = new File("tempFile.jpg");

                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    while(input.read(buffer) > 0){
                        fos.write(buffer);                        
                    }
                    Image image = new Image(tempFile.toURI().toURL().toString());
                    c1.setImage(image);
                }
                for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    c1.addEmployee(new Employee());
                }

                companyData.add(c1);
            }            
        }
        catch(SQLException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(MainController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(MainController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you So match ,  I'm gonna try this  :D  , hope  it will work  for  me  with  some  changes   .